# Is there way the hide/block the navigation bar in android 2.3

Tags: android, button, navigationbar, blocking

At this moment I'm making a quiz application in android 2.3 for some students. I don't want the students to be able to click on the navigation bar during the test, because then they can go to the internet browser to find answers for the quiz.

Is it possible to hide or block the navigation bar in android 2.3 so that I have less chance the students know how to go to the internet on the phone to find the answers? I know it is possible to hide the navigation bar on android 4.0+ but I also want this same feature in android 2.3 if it is even possible. I know that it is possible to block the back button (with `onbackpressed` and then do nothing) and also the home button in a weird/bad way (with `onkeydown`), but then there is still the third "recent used apps" button which I don't know how to block.

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().hide()`

Comment: When i add the library android.support.v7 to my project i can use this but when i extend my class from ActionBarActivity i get a runtime error that the project can't find the class anymore. I also put the classname, etc. in the androidmanifast but still he can't find the class. How do i fix this? Do i also need to add the support library to the androidmanifest?

Comment: AppCompat is a library project and its only referenced if you do it right it should work

Comment: I followed the official online tutorials on how to add these libraries in eclipse but still it doesn't work! :( But also when i search for actionbar in google it only shows the action/titlebar at the top of the screen but will this also hide the navigation bar at the bottom?